# Is there any chance to retrieve data on a database(sql) to a smart contract

Tags: contract-development, database

I want to write a smart contract that gets id numbers as inputs and then retrieve data that are recorded in a database.Is there any specific database for that process.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking!

Comment: You don't have direct access to components outside of the blockchain like an external database. You have to use an external service like an oracle to retrieve data on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not any database/method to do that. You have to must implement a python script between your deployed smartcontract and SQL database.

Comment: Doesn't have to be Python!